# Size of $X\setminus g(X)$ for $g(x)$ the closest $y$ to $x$ with $X_k\sim Unif(A)$

Tags: probability-theory, geometric-probability, discrete-geometry

$\newcommand{\Unif}{\mathop{\rm Unif}}
\newcommand{\argmin}{\mathop{\rm argmin}}$
Let A be a set in the plane (we could have something more general here). Let $X_k\sim \Unif(A)$, $k=1,2,\dots, n$. Denote $X=\{x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n\}$.

Define

$$g(x) = \argmin_{y\in X\setminus \{x\}} |x-y|$$

and then the random variable

$$M=\#X\setminus g(X).$$

I'm interested in how the set $A$ affects $\mathbb{E}[M]$.

---

**Notes**:

- The parameter $n$ is at loose here, but we can consider it going to infinity.
- Also, consider the set $A$ to be open and bounded (the discrete case ($A$ being finite, for the uniform distribution to exist) might also be interesting but I'd like to think of the "shape" of the set).
- $A$ could also be a sphere or torus, if you like.

Comment: Oops, I'll edit!

Comment: Indeed it seems a very interesting problem! A numerical simulation suggests that for the unit square $A = [0,1]^2$ $M$ is approximately normal, which is kind of reasonable because $$M = \sum_{x \in X} \mathbf{1}\{ x \notin g(X) \} $$ is a sum of identically distributed Bernoulli variables which is presumably only weakly correlated.